# Github Deployment Showing Blank

Tags: github

I deployed a repo on github, I changed setting to master branch, but the page is showing blank, this is the only repo that I am encountering this issue, I have attached the link as well as the HTML and CSS, can someone help?  Thank you.

https://github.com/Sunny-Liao/Bootstrap-Portfolio

https://sunny-liao.github.io/Bootstrap-Portfolio/

```css
h1{
    width:720px;
}
 div.container {
    width:750px;
}
 .Portfolio {
    color: teal;
}
div.left {
    padding:28px; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:320px; 
    height:320px; 
    margin:10px; 
    float:left; 
    background:#ebebeb;
    display:block;
}
 .relative {
    position:relative;
    background-color:teal;
    font-size: 30px;
    bottom:18px;
    color:white;
}
 
div.right {
    padding:28px; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:320px; 
    height:320px; 
    margin:10px; 
    background:#ebebeb; 
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Portfolio - Sunny Liao</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       
        <h1><div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white; border border-dark; text-white bg-dark; text-center">Sunny Liao</div></h1>
        
        <ul class="p-3 nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="active">
                <a class="nav-link; text-muted p-4 font-weight-bold" href="#">About</a>
            </li> 
            <li class="active">
                <a class="nav-link; text-primary; p-4 font-weight-bold" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a class="nav-link; text-muted p-4 font-weight-bold" href="#">Contact</a>
             </li>
        </ul>

        <hr>

    <div class="container">

         <div class="left">
            <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/bonjour-word-hello-french-fashionable-calligraphy-vector-illustration-white-background-blue-ink-smear-icons-70128078.jpg" alt="French" width="220px" height="265px">
            <div class="relative">French</div>
        </div>
                
        <div class="right">
            <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/young-girl-do-yoga-cute-cartoon-woman-character-sitting-lotus-pose-healthy-lifestyle-yoga-pad-fitness-clothes-relax-exerci-71211151.jpg" alt="Yoga" width="220px" height="265px">
            <div class="relative">Yoga</div>
        </div>
        
        <br>

        <div class="left">
            <img src="http://www.customs.gov.kh/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/java-256x256.png" alt="Coding" width="220px" height="265px">
            <div class="relative">Coding</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="right">
            <img src="https://d2kk6b9ui4akzl.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/image/700x560/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/9/7/9780735214170_1.jpg" alt="Reading" width="220px" height="265px">
            <div class="relative">Reading</div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
        
        
    
        
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To clarify, you are using GitHub pages, correct?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for reading my post.